# TailwindCSS animations on conditionally rendered components in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

If I am conditionally rendering a component depending on some state, how can I animate its transition between its open and closed states in React with TailwindCSS?

```
{successMessage && (
              <div className="flex transition-all ease-in-out duration-300 bg-gray-200 w-44 items-center justify-between px-2 rounded">
                <p>Added to watchlist!</p>
                <button onClick={() => setSuccessMessage(false)}>X</button>
              </div>
            )}
```

This code half works but there is no animation or transition period to it. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can do as MB_ suggested in their answer or you can provide some actual fade animations or like.

Answer (score 2):

The "official" solution is to use [Headless UI's `Transition` component](https://headlessui.com/react/transition).

Headless UI is created and maintained by the same authors of Tailwind CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
  <div className={`flex transition-all ease-in-out duration-300 bg-gray-200 w-44 items-center justify-between px-2 rounded ${your_state ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'}`}>
   ...
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work

Comment: @FurkanÖztürk, post a new question and share your code

Comment: This will visually work but it can cause some trouble with A11y since items with opacity 0 can still be focused with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Two states works great.
With first one add/remove "hidden" class.
And with second one change opacity/height/translate or what you need for animation.

Use useEffect and setTimeout with 0 delay for changing the state of secondState. like below:

```
useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
  setSecondState(firstState)
}, 0) }, [firstState])

<div className={`${firstState ? "hidden" : ""} ${secondState ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"}`} />
```

Comment: No clue if this is a "good" solution, but it was what worked for me. Genius lol. Only comment I would add is that you may want to set the delay to something a little more than 0 (10 worked consistently for me). At 0ms timeout, sometimes it didn't trigger as expected. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend AOS libary to do this, as you would need to do some more work to make this work with TailwindCSS.

Try this

**Install Aos**

```
npm install aos --save
```

**Put in your file**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import AOS from 'aos';
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

useEffect(() => {
  AOS.init({
    duration : 1000
  });
}, []);
```

You can change duration as you like.

> Add as attribute to HTML tag
> data-aos="animation_name"

Example

```html
 <div> data-aos="fadeIn" </div>
```

Extra Attributes you can use

```html
    data-aos="fade-up"
    data-aos-offset="200"
    data-aos-delay="50"
    data-aos-duration="1000"
    data-aos-easing="ease-in-out"
    data-aos-mirror="true"
    data-aos-once="false"
    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"
```

[List of all animation](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

[Documentation](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos)